# Setting up wifi for 50 devices

Tags: router, network, access-point

We are setting up our company's new workplace. We need to setup wifi so 50 concurrent connections can be handled without any issues. We are taking 150mbps connection. I want to know what sort of wifi router and access point/wifi extender we need for it to work smoothly.

Please suggest wifi router specs I should be looking for while buying.

Comment: Unfortunately all product or resource recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: Just need the specifications I should be looking for. Like its should be a gigabit router with ac support etc.

Comment: Is there other forum I can ask this question?

Comment: You could try to ask this on [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Although specific product recommendation is off-topic, providing clue on which spec to look at, and which value are recommended for a specific load should be on-topic .

Comment: Here's a rule of thumb:  Each access point should have no more than 15-20 clients associated to it.  So you'd need 2-3 APs.

Comment: @Kumar could you specify what you mean by "We are taking 150mbps connection" is that your internet or MPLS connection?

Comment: Just make sure you look for quality name product and follow other comments and answers here. Don't go to Target and Walmart to get your wi-fi devices, look at Cisco, WatchGuard, Netgear, Juniper, Rukus, only quality products. Retail products are not recommended for larger installation.

Answer (score 3):

As per comment from Ron Trunk i'll post this answer:

Depending on what kind of access point and the underlying network design/topology a rule of thumb is 15-25 but if its just web and email traffic you can have more. Just remember that you should have a gigabit port on the AP.

Also wireless is half duplex when you are calculating per device throughput. If you also enable 802.11n/ac that can cause your gigabit port on the AP to be your bottleneck. So you also have to take into account how many APs will connect to a switch and how the connection is from that switch back to your core.

Now for 50 some users/devices, I would, as written by Ron Trunk have at least 2-3 APs in that area and design that area for high density.